# JSON data into scope.body variable

Tags: java, angularjs

I have a problem with angular syntax, when i want to load JSON data into scope.body variable.

It is my script.js

```
function SortableTableCtrl() {
var scope = this;

// dane
// a - Name, b - City, C - Country
scope.head = {
    a: "Nazwa lokalu",
    b: "Miasto",
    c: "Państwo"
};

var myapp=angular.module('App',[]);
myapp.controller('SortableTableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    scope.body = null;
    $http.get('dane.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            scope.body=data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {          
    });
}); 

scope.sort = {
    column: 'b',
    descending: false
};

scope.selectedCls = function(column) {
    return column == scope.sort.column && 'sort-' + scope.sort.descending;
};

scope.changeSorting = function(column) {
    var sort = scope.sort;
    if (sort.column == column) {
        sort.descending = !sort.descending;
    } else {
        sort.column = column;
        sort.descending = false;
    }
};
```

}

and it is JSON file

```
[ 
  {
    a : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    b : "Berlin",
    c : "Germany"
  },
  {
    a : "Berglunds snabbköp",
    b : "Lulea",
    c : "Sweden"
  },
  {
    a : "Centro comercial ",
    b : "México D.F.",
    c : "Mexico"
  },
  {
    a : "Ernst Handel",
    b : "Graz",
    c : "Austria"
  },
  {
    a : "FISSA Fabrica Inter",
    b : "Madrid",
    c : "Spain"
  },
  {
    a : "Galería del gastrónomo",
    b : "Barcelona",
    c : "Spain"
  },
  {
    a : "Island Trading",
    b : "Cowes",
    c : "UK"
  },
  {
    a : "Königlich  Essen",
    b : "Brandenburg",
    c : "Germany"
  },
  {
    a : "Laughing Bacchus",
    b : "Vancouver",
    c : "Canada"
  }


]
```

***Error:***

```
yntaxError: Unexpected token a
    at Object.parse (native)
    at uc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:15:483)
    at $b (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:82:360)
(...)
```

I've tried many diffrent ways but still doesnt work.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

JSON property names should be enclosed in double quotes(`"`) .

use

```
[ 
     {
        "a" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "b" : "Berlin",
        "c" : "Germany"
      },...so on
]
```

validate your json before using it : http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Without quotes, you are specifying the key as a variable `a`. If you want the letter `a` to be the key, use:

```
[ 
  {
    "a" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "b" : "Berlin",
    "c" : "Germany"
  },
```